# Where can I read about entering in my math in the correct format?

Tags: support

I'm not really sure what to search for.  I didn't find the info in the Faq.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934)?

Comment: Nope.  I didn't actually know it was called latex.

Comment: Just know that it is pronounced as La-Te'kh rather then pronunciation latex of the rubbery material of the prophylactic many people use in this day and age.

Comment: I believe there are variant pronunciations for LaTeX, and Leslie Lamport refuses to endorse one of them...

Answer (score 3):

It is actually in [our detailed list of FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange) which is linked to from the [brief FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) that is linked to at the top of every page on the main site.

So yes, the [information is out there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).